# Can't see images posted by other users

Tags: support, images

I can't see images posted by other users on any of the stack exchange sites. Attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a problem on your end... Those images are from three different sources, and only the one in the right-side bar could even potentially be hosted by Stack Exchange. Try checking your connectivity to Imgur and Gravatar?

Comment: Where are when you're attempting to access it? If you're under a proxy, imgur might be blocked.

Comment: @Bernie: There is no proxy at the place from where I am accessing.

Comment: @animuson: How to check connectivity to Imgur & Gravatar?

Comment: @Shivanand, have you tried pinging the addresses?

Comment: @Bernie, How to ping? through command prompt?

Comment: @Shivanand: Yes. The command syntax for all platforms is `ping imgur.com` or `ping gravatar.com`. On Windows, you'll enter this into `cmd.exe`; on Mac, it's `Terminal.app`; on Linux, it's `gnome-terminal` or `konsole`.

Comment: Do you use an adblocker?